# Error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before XXX (all kinds of parameters)

Tags: c, linux, compiler-errors

Just getting started with Linux learning. Ubuntu 18.04, linux-kernel 4.15 .
Trying these simple code:

[image: error]

I supposed there's something wrong with stdio.h, but failed to figured it out. Expecting some help.

```
#include<stdio.h>

char s[20];
"""
unsigned long ul = 1234567890;
sprintf(s,"%u",ul);
s="asb";
printf("%s\n",s);
```

Comment: Remove `"""` on line 4. You may have additional problems. What is `"""` supposed to do or be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code:

- `main` is missing which is the default entry point.
- What is `"""` used for - it induces error.
- You are using `%u` which is for `unsigned` type where as `ul` is of `unsigned long` type, use `%lu` instead.
- You are assigning a string to `s = "asb"` which is not the correct way - use `strcpy` or `strcat` depending on what you are trying to achieve.

Here is a functional version:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char s[20];
    unsigned long ul = 1234567890;
    sprintf(s,"%lu",ul);
    strcat(s,"asb");        //CAN USE STRCPY AS WELL
    printf("%s\n",s);
    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT:** `1234567890asb`

Comment: Actually it's my mistakes using c. Thanks for help!

Answer (score -1):

A couple of errors. First [Read this](https://www.techonthenet.com/c_language/comments.php)  on how to write comments within C code. Also your string initialization is wrong. Here's the correct solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>
const char s[] = "asb";
printf("%s\n",s);
```

Comment: Where is the rest if the program gone? If is full of errors.

Comment: Actually it's my mistakes using c. Thanks for help!